# Pin Python minor version in Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Tags: 18.04, python, python3

I am running software which depends on the installed *minor* Python version.

I was surprised to see that something changed my Python3 version from Python3.6.8 to Python3.6.9, which has caused some software to break.

What is the recommended way of pinning a *minor* Python version in Ubuntu? Can I install Python from source and have 3.6.8 live alongside 3.6.9?

All guides and questions that I see talk about either going from Python2 to Python3 or from Python3.X to Python3.Y.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pinning the version, I'd strongly suggest to fix your program.

Python uses semantic versioning, that means an updated number in the 3rd position as in 3.6.8 to 3.6.9 is only a minor update or in other words a bug fix.

Fixing your problem should not be a big problem. I am happy to offer my help.

If you really need 3.6.8, you should probably download the source and compile it.